# What is the equivalent of widget clientdata or userdata in C#?

Tags: c#

In C programming when you create a widget (or control) most gui library APIs allow you to "reference" client data (calling application) via the widget by adding clientdata to that widget; typically of the nature (XWindows):

```
XtVaSetValues(widget, XmNuserData, data, NULL);
```

Where data is a pointer to a variable stored at the client end. This data can be got using the complement of XtVaSetValues - XtVaGetValues.

Is there an equivalence in C#. I've been looking to do something similar with a command button in C# (.NET framework, winForms). I went down the DataBindings road but it got me nowhere and left me rather confused. I'm pretty new to C# so please forgive me if this makes no sense to an experienced C# programmer.

Comment: Which UI framework? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: In Winforms, there is a `Control.Tag` property of type `object` that you can attach miscellaneous data to.

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks. It's a winForm application. I'll try the Tag property. Cheers.